# Printing arrays created in a class

Tags: c++

I am trying to print an array created inside the class initializer. I have tried a number of ways but my findings are that I have to use pointers for this problem. The code:

```
#include <iostream>

// arr.h
class Arr
{
private:
    const int sizeVertical;
    const int sizeHorizontal;
    int *ptr;
public:
    Arr(int sizeVertical, int sizeHorizontal);
    void Init();
    void Print();
};

// arr.cpp
Arr::Arr(int _sizeVertical, int _sizeHorizontal)
    :   sizeVertical(_sizeVertical),
        sizeHorizontal(_sizeHorizontal)
{
    int arr2d[sizeVertical][sizeHorizontal];
    ptr = &arr2d[0][0];
}

void Arr::Init()
{
    for(int i=0; i<sizeVertical; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<sizeHorizontal; j++)
        {
            *(ptr + i * sizeHorizontal + j) = i+j;
        }
    }
}

void Arr::Print()
{
    for(int i=0; i<sizeVertical; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<sizeHorizontal; j++)
        {
            std::cout<<*(ptr + i * sizeHorizontal + j)<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}

// main.cpp
int main()
{
    Arr test(4,3);
    test.Init();
    test.Print();
}
```

Inside the method (Init) where I defined the array I can also print the array in the same way as used in the method (Print). But when trying to print the array in a different method the output looks very strange. The output:

```
0
22025
955388640
32767
10
0
-1247975061
32668
1
3
-1549041632
22025
```

Any ideas?

Comment: _"I have tried a number of ways but my findings are that I have to use pointers for this problem."_ No, the idiomatic way would be to use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create local array and assign address of it's first element to the pointer. But the array is gone when constructor finishes, so the address stored in pointer is already invalidated.

Acessing this address in Undefined Behaviour, meaning anything can happen when you run that code.

The best way to handle this is to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, as suggested in comments:

```
#include <vector>

class Arr
{
private:
    const int sizeVertical;
    const int sizeHorizontal;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr2d;
public:
    Arr(int sizeVertical, int sizeHorizontal);
    void Init();
    void Print();
};

// arr.cpp
Arr::Arr(int _sizeVertical, int _sizeHorizontal)
    :   sizeVertical(_sizeVertical),
        sizeHorizontal(_sizeHorizontal),
        arr2d(_sizeVertical, std::vector<int>(_sizeHorizontal))
{
}
```

`Init` can use `[][]` for easy access instead of pointer arithmetic.

Note that you no longer need your `sizeVertical` and `sizeHorizontal`, you can use `arr2d.size()` and `arr2d[0].size()` instead:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr2d.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<arr2d[0].size(); j++)
    {
    }
}
```

Personally I think named constants are more readable than this, but they would require you to never change the size of vectors. As noted in comments, you can also create such constants locally, in function where you need them.

---

You could also use dynamic memory allocation, but I don't recommend that. It's difficult to properly manage memory and you will have to follow the [Rule of Three/Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Good one. I think `sizeVertical` and `sizeHorizontal` are no longer required now. You may consider removing them.

Comment: @KunalPuri True, but I think they are more readable than `arr2d.size()` and `arr2d[0].size()`. I'll add that in answer for OP to decide.

Comment: You can have local variables for it. For the sake of readability. But I don't think there is a valid reason to have them as data members. They will increase the size of object, just for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your array has been deallocated.

```
Arr::Arr(int _sizeVertical, int _sizeHorizontal)
    :   sizeVertical(_sizeVertical),
        sizeHorizontal(_sizeHorizontal)
{
    int arr2d[sizeVertical][sizeHorizontal]; // arr2d allocated.
    ptr = &arr2d[0][0];
} // arr2d dies here
```

Instead, as rightly suggested by [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96), You may use `std::vector< std::vector<int> >`. If you don't want to do it, you may use dynamic memory, though I won't recommend it.

```
Arr::Arr(int _sizeVertical, int _sizeHorizontal)
    :   sizeVertical(_sizeVertical),
        sizeHorizontal(_sizeHorizontal)
{
    ptr = new int[sizeVertical * sizeHorizontal];
}
```

Make Sure that you free the dynamic memory allocated to it by having `delete` in destructor.

```
Arr::~Arr()
{
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

This is known as **RAII Pattern** which guarantees deinitialization.

**Edit**:

If you don't plan to change the dimensions of array, then I would highly recommend you to use `std::array`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<int sizeVertical, int sizeHorizontal>
class Arr
{
    private:
    std::array<std::array<int, sizeHorizontal>, sizeVertical> arr;

    public:
    Arr() { }
    void Init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeVertical; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeHorizontal; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = i + j;
            }
        }
    }
    void Print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeVertical; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeHorizontal; j++) {
                std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }

            std::cout << "\n";
        }   
    }
};

int main()
{
    Arr<10, 2> arr;
    arr.Init();

    arr.Print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize pointer to int `ptr` with address of automatic variable `arr2d` in constructor. Automatic variables allocated in stack, and destroyed automatically once you leave code scope `{ ... }` where they are allocated. So, after you leave your constructor, address in `ptr` is no longer valid because `arr2d` is destroyed. You may use dynamic memory allocation in constructor

```
Arr::Arr(int _sizeVertical, int _sizeHorizontal)
    :   sizeVertical(_sizeVertical),
        sizeHorizontal(_sizeHorizontal)
{
    ptr = new int[sizeVertical * sizeHorizontal];
}
```

Do not forget to free it in a destructor:

```
Arr::~Arr(void)
{
    delete[] ptr;
}
```